# Mongoose findOne() in several collections

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm building a deletion process where I need to find out if a certain document is referenced from another documents before deleting the original document.

In the example below, I need to find out if a given Company is used somewhere in my other documents:

Model metadata:

```
Company = {
    id: ID,
    name: name
}

User = {
    id: ID,
    name: name,
    company_id: ID
}

Application = {
     id: ID,
     type: string,
     company_id: ID
}

...
```

Here is what I would do using asynchronous calls:

```
const checkInUse = async (company_id) =>  {

     let ret = await UserModel.findOne({ company_id: company_id });

     if (ret) return true;

     ret = await ApplicationModel.findOne({ company_id: company_id });

     if (ret) return true;

     ...

     return false;
}
```

I have some dozen of collections, so some checks would take several calls to `findOne()`, and that's what I want to avoid.

Is there is a better way of doing this check ?

Comment: only `Promise.all` to speed it up a bit.

Comment: Not necessary. Using asynchronous calls will fire all queries. In syncrhonous mode, if first query finds an occurency the next queries will not be issued...

Comment: why are you doing `findOne` instead you can delete them directly?

Comment: It's "not necessary" for a particular case. Overall with even distribution of true/false it will be faster on application side, even tho it will create extra load on db side.